# Equivalent to in org.gnome.ScreenSaver KDE

Tags: gnome, kde, screensaver

I have a script that automatically disables my USB mouse when the screen is locked or idle. (Because my mouse is too sensible). It monitors the activity org.gnome.ScreenSaver, like this:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | ( while read line; do ....
```

I have switched to KDE last week, and this, obviously has stopped working. I have tried using org.kde.ScreenSaver  , but it did not work.
What should I use, so that the script detects the locked screen/ idle screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer after analyzing dbus-monitor output.
Had to change the line to

'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'